# Programmatically filling Excel column with all possible sums of two value combinations

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill a column with the number of calculations depending on a number provided as an argument. For example, if I plug in that I need to buy `50` widgets from two possible widget types:

```
Widget 1: $1.00
Widget 2: $1.15
```

I would like to be able to fill a column with 50 different values, each being the total price for 50 "widget 1"s, the total price for 49 "widget 1"s and 1 "widget 2", etc. Here's an example showing a spreadsheet for the total price for the first possible combination:

[image]

The idea being that just by changing `B4`/`X` in the spreadsheet, I can get the sum for each combination of widgets for X widgets total, with each sum being in its own cell. I have the beginnings of a formula to calculate this that seems like it might work for iterations of the different widget 1/2 mixes, but the B4 value is hardcoded and I also don't know how to carry the formula down column `C` the same number of times as the value in `B4`. Is VBA likely my best bet here?

```
=((50+0)*B2)+((50-50)*B3)
```

Comment: Sorry, question for clarification, if you have 2 types of widgets and you say you want 50, does that mean you want to calculate 50/0, 49/1, 48/2, 47/3 ... 5/45, 4/46, 3/47, 2/48, 1/49, 0/50 ...? Is that what you mean? Left hand side being widget 1 and right being widget 2.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you try to find a solution where there are two variables that can change: the number of widget 1 and the number of widget 2? In that case I would look at the Solver Add-In, which comes standard in most MS Excel installations.

Comment: If I plug '20' in for B4, I'd like to calculate the sum of 20 widget 1s, 19 widget 1s and one widget 2, 18 widget 1s and 2 widget 2s, etc...I know this is a little confusing, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `ROW()` function like this:

```
=IF(OR(ROW()-ROW($C$2)<0,$B$4<ROW()-ROW($C$2)),"",(($B$4-(ROW()-ROW($C$2)))*$B$2+(ROW()-ROW($C$2))*$B$3))
```

You have to pull it down as long as the maximum possible value of B4. If B4's actual value is smaller than the maximum, the formula will result in empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to z32a7ul's answer, but maybe a little shorter:

```
    =IF($B$4+2-ROW()>=0,($B$4+2-ROW())*$B$2+(ROW()-2)*$B$3,"Out of Bounds")
```

The formula 1) checks if you exceeded the number of possible combinations of the widget summation and 2) pastes the sum if you haven't or 3) writes "out of bounds" if you  have. Start in row 2 (e.g. cell `C2`) and pull down.

The formula assumes a) that you start in `row 2` (otherwise, change every 2 in the formula to the row in which you start).
The widgets prices are in cells `B2` and `B3` (otherwise change the reference, and keep the `$` signs, so when dragging the formula down, the references are kept)
The number of combinations is in `B4` (again, adjust if necessary)

Comment: It really is similar. But its shortness makes it also less flexible: if you insert a row above C2 or if you move the whole thing with Ctrl+x, Ctrl+v, this won't work because the starting row is hardcoded (2).

Comment: Agree, but I was hoping that the OP might find this more understandable and then be able to use these kind of formulas in the future him/herself.